# I'm getting exception when query with Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Here is the exception

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'.
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

Here is my code

```
List<int> items = new List<int>(){1,5,7,14};

var selecteditems = (from u in _entities.UserInfo
                     join type in items on u.TypeID equals  type
                     where u.UserId == userid
                     select new UserClass
                     {
                         FirstName = u.FirstName,
                         LastName = u.LastName
                     }).ToList();
```

Any ideas what can cause the exception? and maybe some workaround?

Comment: this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982066/why-wont-this-linq-join-statement-work) might help

Answer (score 3):

**For EF4**
Get rid of the join on items and add `&& items.Contains(u.TypeID)` to the where clause.

```
int[] items = new[] { 1, 5, 7, 14 }; 
var selecteditems = (from u in _entities.UserInfo 
                        where u.UserId == userid && items.Contains(u.TypeID)
                        select new UserClass {
                                            FirstName = u.FirstName, 
                                            LastName = u.LastName, 
                                            Email = ul.Email
                                    }).ToList();
```

**For EF1**
EF1 does not support collection-valued parameters (i.e. `Contains()`) This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0) contains code for a utility method called `BuildContainsExpression` that can be used to get around this restriction.

**UPDATE**
I updated the answer to reflect comments from Craig Stuntz regarding solutions for EF1 & EF4

Comment: I got this error when using contains LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' method, 
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Jorge try using `int[]` instead of `List<int>` for items.

Comment: @Brian: This works with both `int[]` and `List<int>`, but requires EF 4.

Comment: I got this error Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I'm using 3.5 and at this point cannot convert to 4.0, any solutions will work in my case?

Comment: @Jorge: Google `BuildContainsExpression`