# A Problem in Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

What is wrong with this code ?
I got this exception **on the last line**:

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'.
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

```
var query = from colT in dal.TBL_Gharardad 
            select colT;  

if(lstTarafeGharardadIds.Count>0)
    query = from q in query 
            join id in lstTarafeGharardadIds on q.TarafeGharardadId equals id 
            select q;

dgvListeGharardad.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

The lastTarafeGharardadIds is a `List<int>`

I also test

```
dgvListeGharardad.DataSource = query;
```

Everything works well if `if` expression equals to false and this code

```
query = from q in query 
        join id in lstTarafeGharardadIds on q.TarafeGharardadId equals id 
        select q;
```

doesn't run. But I can't understand I got the error on the last line (on this code):

```
dgvListeGharardad.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Format your code so it's readable - then people might be more likely to read it :)

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. If possible, also remove unnecessary pieces of it

Comment: What is the item type in `lstTarafeGharardadIds`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think linq can't join between an in-memory collection (lstTarafeGharardadIds) and a database table (dal.TBL_Gharardad, dal.v_Gharardad...).

Similar problem: [Why won't this LINQ join statement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982066/why-wont-this-linq-join-statement-work)

This should work:

```
var query = (from colT in dal.TBL_Gharardad select colT).AsEnumerable();;
if (lstTarafeGharardadIds.Count>0)
    query = from q in query 
            join id in lstTarafeGharardadIds on q.TarafeGharardadId equals id 
            select q;
dgvListeGharardad.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thats hard to read!

Anyways, assuming your naming convention is right. you end up with: select colV. Selecting a column results in selecting a IEnumerable rather then a primitive value which your dataSource requires.

You can try and use SelectMany to select the actual value you need

```
dgvListeGharardad.DataSource = query.SelectMany(x => x.[YourProperty]).ToList();
```